# Access content types fields in template

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Trying to retrieve all the data from a content type (the Article content type from the core installation).

I think I have managed to get the records, but I can't access the properties.

This is what I have in the controller

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'Article');
$items = $query->execute();
```

When I try to dump the items I'm getting

> array(2) {
>     [3]=>
>     string(1) "2"
>     [4]=>
>     string(1) "3"
>   }

There is 2 results and I have 2 articles so I think this is the good way to get theses articles. But then in my twig templates I don't know how to call the properties.

This is empty result

```
{% for article in items %}
    <li>{{article.body}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Tried with .title and .name too.

Actually I think that what I'm getting here are just the articles ids but not the properties, so I guess I miss something again here.

Thanks for the assistance

EDIT: Also tried this, but it makes it crash

```
$items_ids = $query->execute();
$items = Article::loadMultiple($items_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up by find out what was wrong with that, I needed to use Node for the load in controller and then .field.value in templates to render.

Controller

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'Article');
$items_ids = $query->execute();
$items = Node::loadMultiple($items_ids);
```

Twig

```
{% for article in items %}
    <li>{{article.title.value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```